# Can't change color of a shown message in fragment when I parse data

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change color of the text that I parsed. It depends on a raddiobutton that is an enum in my code. I am new to android and I appreciate all the help!
Here is my enum:

```
enum curricularNote{LECTURE, LAB, OTHERS};
```

Whatever I run it, it colors my message only in red:

```
                TextView tvMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.mesaj);
                if(notes.getCurNote().toString().equals("Lecture"))
                    tvMessage.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
              else
                  if(notes.getCurNote().equals("Lab"))
                    tvMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
               else
             // else if(notes.getCurNote().equals("Others"))
                    tvMessage.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Provide the code where current note change happens

Comment: By using debug or by writing System.out.println(notes.getCurNote().toString())  before if statements and check what actually get for the notes.getCurNote().toString()

Comment: @HimashiRodrigo It worked using the statement, thank you! But I still can't figure out why before it didnt work and why it does now.

Comment: @HimashiRodrigo apperently just adding System.out.println(notes.getCurNote().toString()) solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set value to textview then set color based on value:

```
Textview t = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.tw_id);
    t.setText(value);
    
    
    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("LECTURE")
     t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("LAB")
     t.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("OTHER")
     t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```